# MySQL max_connctions+1

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, max-connections, connections

I experienced an incident that my connections are full. Even I as an administrator I cannot log to MySQL due to "too many connections.". Does anybody knows how to setup this max_connections+1? I use version 5.6.14. Thank you very much.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is your basic problem: You most likely have many users in `mysql.user` other than `root@localhost` with the [SUPER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) privilege. Please note the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/too-many-connections.html) in your question:

> mysqld actually permits max_connections+1 clients to connect. The extra connection is reserved for use by accounts that have the [SUPER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) privilege. By granting the [SUPER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) privilege to administrators and not to normal users (who should not need it), an administrator can connect to the server and use [SHOW PROCESSLIST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-processlist.html) to diagnose problems even if the maximum number of unprivileged clients are connected. [See Section 13.7.5.30, “SHOW PROCESSLIST Syntax”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-processlist.html).

You need to run this

```
SELECT CONCAT(QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host)) FROM mysql.user
WHERE super_priv='Y' and user<>'root';
```

You need to take away the [SUPER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) privilege from those users.

The fastest way to revoke the [SUPER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) privilege from those users is to login to mysql as `root@localhost` and execute the following:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET super_priv='N' WHERE
WHERE super_priv='Y' and user<>'root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

**NOTE #1 :** I have discussed this before on `Jul 06, 2012` in [How to resolve too many connections and fatal error in mysql running on vps](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20479/how-to-resolve-too-many-connections-and-fatal-error-in-mysql-running-on-vps/20504#20504)

**NOTE #2 :** If you have other mysql users doing database backups and cronjobs, you need to make sure those users have all needs privileges for their respective operations after removing the [SUPER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) privilege.

**NOTE #3 :** If you do not use other users to connect to mysql, you need to create extra users that do no have all privileges, but still have enough privileges for needed operations.