# mysql max_connections limit reset

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, connections, limits

Last week I updated mysql max_connections to 1000 from 151 using

```
use mysql;
set global max_connections = 1000;
```

Today there was a power outage at the hosting company and the servers shut down and were then restarted.  After restart, the max_connections variable was reset to 151.

Is this default behavior?  How can I prevent max_connections global from getting reset?

Reference:

```
MySQL 5.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is the default behavior. How ? The default value for max_connections is 151.

This is true for [MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections), [MySQL 5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections), and [MySQL 5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections)

If `/etc/my.cnf` does not have max_connections, then 151 comes up as max_connections.

You can just run `set global max_connections = 1000;`.

Your hosting company must put that entry in `/etc/my.cnf` for you

```
[mysqld]
max_connections=1000
```

Otherwise, every restart of mysqld will reset max_connections to 151.

I have suggested this before

- `Jul 06, 2012` : [How to resolve too many connections and fatal error in mysql running on vps](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20479/how-to-resolve-too-many-connections-and-fatal-error-in-mysql-running-on-vps/20504#20504)

Answer (score 0):

To address the other part of your question...

Whether or not the hosting company lets you change the variable, let's discuss *why* more than 151 is needed.

If this is a web site then each page should connect, do some stuff, and quickly disconnect.  It is a rare web site that need more than 20 connections.

If the web server, such as Apache, is configured poorly, such as `MaxClients` = some big number, that that should be fixed.  152 (or even 30) web clients vying for resources will simply bog down, stretching out latency, *without* imporoving throughput.

If you have "slow" queries that keep connections open a long time; let's look at them; speeding them up may solve your "need" for more than 151 connections.

If you have a seriously overloaded system, consider Replication, wherein you could have multiple Slaves, each providing 151 connections for *readonly* queries.

PS:  MySQL 8.0 will let you set globals in a different way.